# check that a word is an isogram with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How do i check that a given word is an isogram with pure javascript, using a function. the function must return true or false.

*An isogram is a word with a repeated character.*

I know this code works, but i need a better solution.

```
function isIsogram(word){
    x = false; y = false;
    for(i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        wordl = word.substring(0,i)
        wordr = word.substring(i)
        x = wordl.includes(word.charAt(i))
        y = wordr.includes(word.charAt(i))
        //console.log(x,wordl,wordr)
    }
    return x&&y
}
isIsogram("thomas");//False
isIsogram("moses"); //True
```

Comment: if you don't mind using es6, you could do this: `isIsogram = x=> x.length == new Set(x.split('')).size`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple approach using `.split()` and `.every()`:

```js
let isIsogram = (str) => str.split("").every((c, i) => str.indexOf(c) == i);
                            
console.log(isIsogram("thomas"));   /* no repeating letter */
console.log(isIsogram("moses"));    /* s repeat 2 times */
console.log(isIsogram("hello"));    /* l repeat 2 times */
console.log(isIsogram("world"));    /* no repeating letter */
console.log(isIsogram("a b c"));    /* space character repeat 2 times */
```

**Docs:**

- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: How can this be improved to ignore letter cases?

Comment: Please can you explain the (c, i) variables. I am a beginner JS coder and the docs are a little difficult to understand

Comment: @SamuelBruton c=character and i=index. The function splitting the string, then checking every character and it's index and then matching index of character to index of string.

Comment: @SamuelBruton It should also be pointed out that the reason why this works is that the indexOf function returns the index of the first occurrence found within the string. Thus if there is another occurrence of this character, the test will fail.

Answer (score 11):

Remove the duplicate letter from string then check both length. if same its an isogram.

```js
function isIsogram(str){
 return str.split('').filter((item, pos, arr)=> arr.indexOf(item) == pos).length == str.length;
}
console.log(isIsogram('thomas'));
console.log(isIsogram('moses'));
```

Answer (score 8):

One way of doing this!

```
function isIsogram(str){
  return !str.match(/([a-z]).*\1/i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on kishea's answer:

```
function isIsogram(sWord)
 {
  for (iCharIndex = 0; iCharIndex < sWord.length; iCharIndex++)
    if (sWord.substring(iCharIndex + 1).includes(sWord.charAt(iCharIndex)))
      return false;
  return true;
 }
```

If the character at the current position (`charAt`) is found (`includes`) to the right of the current position (`substring`), `false` is returned. Otherwise the loop runs to the end and `true` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
const isIsogram = (word) => {
    return new Set(word.toLowerCase()).size === word.length
}

console.log(isIsogram('Thor'));//true
console.log(isIsogram('Loki'));//true
console.log(isIsogram('America'));//false
```

Comment: While this code might provide the right answer, a brief explanation as to why it works goes a long way to teach the OP and others in the community. Please consider adding an explanation to this code snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
function isIsogram(str) {
    return new Set(str.toUpperCase()).size == str.length
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While given a word, this function if splits the word into two, 
That is wordl and wordr respectively.
Both splittings are checked to include a character in the original word. If wordl and wordr both contain any character in the original word. Then surely this is an isogram

```
function isIsogram(word){
    x = false; y = false;
    for(i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        wordl = word.substring(0,i)
        wordr = word.substring(i)
        x = wordl.includes(word.charAt(i))
        y = wordr.includes(word.charAt(i))
        //console.log(x,wordl,wordr)
    }
    return !x&&y
}
isIsogram("thomas");//True
isIsogram("moses"); //False
```

Comment: First, aren't those results backwards? Second, this answer would be improved by a short explanation of how the code works.

Comment: i tested the results thats what i get. just need a better solution

Comment: If you're looking for a better solution, then your attempt should be part of the question, not an answer.

Comment: @kishea `An isogram is a word without a repeated character.` yet the word *moses* has two *s*-es yet it is recognised as an isogram.

Answer (score 0):

What about :

```
> function isIsogram(word) {
... var a = word.split('')
... var b = Array.from(new Set(a))
... return a.length === b.length;
... }
undefined
> isIsogram("mesos")
false
> isIsogram("thomas")
true
```

Or better (checking each char only once) :

```
> function isIsogram2(word) {
... for(var i=0,len=word.length-1;i<len;++i) {
..... var c = word[i]
..... if(word.indexOf(c,i+1) !== -1) return false;
..... }
... return true;
... }
undefined
> isIsogram2("mesos")
false
> isIsogram2("thomas")
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isIsogram(word){
   return !/(.).*\1|\d/i.test(word)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str=prompt('Enter a string');
    var strlen=str.length;

    for(i=0;i<strlen;i++){
       var stc=str.charAt(i);
       var flag=0;
       for(j=0;j<strlen;j++){
        var stk=str.charAt(j);
          if(stc==stk){
            flag=flag+1;
          }
       }

       if(flag!=1){
        break;
       }

    }

    if(flag!=1){
        alert('It is not an isogram');
    }
    else{
        alert('It is an isogram');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isIsogram = (string) => {
    
    const lowerCased = string.toLowerCase()
    
    const result = lowerCased.split('').every((v,i)=>lowerCased.indexOf(v)===i)
    
    return result

}

console.log(isIsogram('ambidExtRously')) // true
console.log(isIsogram('patteRN')) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function isIsogram(word) {

    let uniqueCharacters = new Set(word.split(''));

    uniqueCharacters = Array.from(uniqueCharacters); //get all the unique char

    let charFreq = {}; //e.g {a:2, b:3}

    for (element of uniqueCharacters) {
        charFreq[element] = 0;
    } //set the frequency of each char to zero

    function updateFrequency(element) {
        charFreq[element] += 1;
    }//callback used directly below

    word.split('').forEach(updateFrequency); //for each char encountered, update frequency

    let frequencyOfCharacter = [];

    for (keys in charFreq) {
        frequencyOfCharacter.push(charFreq[keys]);
    }

    function equal(item) {
        return item === frequencyOfCharacter[0];
    }
    //check if all the frequencies are the same, an isogram means all characters occur at the same frequency

    return frequencyOfCharacter.every(equal);
}

console.log(isIsogram('try'), isIsogram('baba'), isIsogram('tests'));
```